# Entity Framework migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Проблема такова: я хочу сделать миграцию через EF для базы данных, но при создании миграции получаю ошибку

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'DiscordBot.Db.SqliteApplicationContext'. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'DiscordBot.Core.Intrerfaces.IConfig' while attempting to activate 'DiscordBot.Db.SqliteApplicationContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Оно не может прокинуть IConfig в SqliteApplicationContext. IConfig - это конфиг для базы данных. Так-же есть класс SqliteConfig:

```
using DiscordBot.Core.Intrerfaces;

namespace DiscordBot.Core.ConfigResults;

public class SqliteConfig : IConfig
{
    public string DataSource { get; set; }

    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

Вот класс SqliteApplicationContext:

```
using DiscordBot.Core.ConfigResults;
using DiscordBot.Core.Intrerfaces;
using DiscordBot.Model.Db.Entities;
using DiscordBot.Model.Db.ModelConfigurators;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DiscordBot.Db;

public class SqliteApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    private SqliteConfig _sqliteConfig;
    
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public SqliteApplicationContext(IConfig config)
    {
        _sqliteConfig = (SqliteConfig)config;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UsersModelConfigurator());
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite();
    }
}
```

В чём может быть проблема? Почему оно не может найти SqliteConfig? Я пытался использовать DI, но получал такую же ошибку.

Comment: А зачем там этот конфиг нужен? Почему нельзя из конфиг файла просто строку в контекст скинуть?

Comment: @tym32167 Да, действительно, Вы правы. Я скинул строку, но получил ошибку того же типа: Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'DiscordBot.Db.SqliteApplicationContext'. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'DiscordBot.Db.SqliteApplicationContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Comment: `Я пытался использовать DI` - как? Покажите код.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ var sqliteConfigLoader = new SqliteConfigLoader();
var sqliteConfig = sqliteConfigLoader.Load("db.json") as SqliteConfig;

var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddSingleton<IConfig>(sqliteConfig);
services.AddDbContext<SqliteApplicationContext>();

var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

Comment: По ссылке статью смотрели? Утилита миграции для своей работы должна создать экземпляр вашего DbContext. Сделать это она может тремя способами: используя Host, используя конструктор без параметров, используя фабрику. Реализуйте один из этих способов.